# ¿Cómo llenar una tabla columna por columna en angular?

Tags: html5, angular

Lo que quiero realizar es imprimir la [matriz MITRE](https://attack.mitre.org/) en una tabla, el detalle es que tengo más datos que indica cuantos elementos se registraron en cada tactica.
El detalle es cuando lleno la tabla la llena fila por fila, pero me gustaria hacerlo columna por columna.
Adjunto el codigo ejemplo de la respuesta de mi backend

```
"tableData": [
            {
                "technique": "Reconnaissance",
                "tactics": [
                    {
                        "tactic": "Active Scanning",
                        "id": "T1595",
                        "total_tickets": 14
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Gather Victim Host Information",
                        "id": "T1592",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Gather Victim Identity Information",
                        "id": "T1589",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Gather Victim Network Information",
                        "id": "T1590",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Gather Victim Org Information",
                        "id": "T1591",
                        "total_tickets": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Phishing for Information",
                        "id": "T1598",
                        "total_tickets": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Search Closed Sources",
                        "id": "T1597",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Search Open Technical Databases",
                        "id": "T1596",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Search Open Websites/Domains",
                        "id": "T1593",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Search Victim-Owned Websites",
                        "id": "T1594",
                        "total_tickets": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "technique": "Resource Development",
                "tactics": [
                    {
                        "tactic": "Acquire Infrastructure",
                        "id": "T1583",
                        "total_tickets": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Compromise Accounts",
                        "id": "T1586",
                        "total_tickets": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Compromise Infrastructure",
                        "id": "T1584",
                        "total_tickets": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Develop Capabilities",
                        "id": "T1587",
                        "total_tickets": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Establish Accounts",
                        "id": "T1585",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Obtain Capabilities",
                        "id": "T1588",
                        "total_tickets": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Stage Capabilities",
                        "id": "T1608",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "technique": "Initial Access",
                "tactics": [
                    {
                        "tactic": "Drive-by Compromise",
                        "id": "T1189",
                        "total_tickets": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Exploit Public-Facing Application",
                        "id": "T1190",
                        "total_tickets": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "External Remote Services",
                        "id": "T1133",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Hardware Additions",
                        "id": "T1200",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Phishing",
                        "id": "T1566",
                        "total_tickets": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Replication Through Removable Media",
                        "id": "T1091",
                        "total_tickets": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Supply Chain Compromise",
                        "id": "T1195",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Trusted Relationship",
                        "id": "T1199",
                        "total_tickets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tactic": "Valid Accounts",
                        "id": "T1078",
                        "total_tickets": 8
                    }
                ]
            }
       ]
```

Anexo también el HTML de la tabla (en este caso, el código imprime solamente una columna, pero no se pasa a la siguiente columna, también aclaro que estoy usando la librería [NG Zorro](https://ng.ant.design))

```
<div class="simple-card">
  <div class="table-header flex between wrap">
    <div class="card-title">
      <span *ngIf="isLoading">Cargando...</span>
      <span *ngIf="!isLoading">{{totalData || 0}} {{title || ''}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table-container">
    <nz-table #basicTable
              [nzShowPagination]="false"
              [nzTotal]="totalData"
              [nzLoading]="isLoading"
              [nzBordered]="true"
              [nzData]="data">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let technique of basicTable.data">{{technique.technique}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let techniqueObject of basicTable.data">
        <tr *ngFor="let tacticObject of techniqueObject.tactics">
          <td>{{tacticObject.tactic}}: {{tacticObject.total_tickets}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
      </tbody>
    </nz-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anexo tambíen la imagen de como se imprime la tabla con el código anterior.
[image: Tabla con el código anterior]

Les agradezco mucho su ayuda.